# most efficient way to go about identifying sub-strings in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, fuzzy-search

i need to search a fairly lengthy string for CPV (common procurement vocab) codes.

at the moment i'm doing this with a simple for loop and str.find()

the problem is, if the CPV code has been listed in a slightly different format, this algorithm won't find it.

what's the most efficient way of searching for all the different iterations of the code within the string? Is it simply a case of reformatting each of the up to 10,000 CPV codes and using str.find() for each instance?

An example of different formatting could be as follows

```
30124120-1 
301241201 
30124120 - 1
30124120 1
30124120.1
```

etc.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a regular expression:

```
>>> cpv = re.compile(r'([0-9]+[-\. ]?[0-9])')
>>> print cpv.findall('foo 30124120-1 bar 21966823.1 baz')
['30124120-1', '21966823.1']
```

(Modify until it matches the CPVs in your data closely.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using any of the functions in `re` (regular expressions for Python). See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for more info.

You can craft a regular expression to accept a number of different formats for these codes, and then use `re.findall` or something similar to extract the information. I'm not certain what a CPV is so I don't have a regular expression for it (though maybe you could see if Google has any?)

Answer (score 1):

```
cpv = re.compile(r'(\d{8})(?:[ -.\t/\\]*)(\d{1}\b)')

for m in re.finditer(cpv, ex):
    cpval,chk = m.groups()
    print("{0}-{1}".format(cpval,chk))
```

applied to your sample data returns

```
30124120-1
30124120-1
30124120-1
30124120-1
30124120-1
```

The regular expression can be read as

```
(\d{8})         # eight digits

(?:             # followed by a sequence which does not get returned
  [ -.\t/\\]*   #   consisting of 0 or more
)               #   spaces, hyphens, periods, tabs, forward- or backslashes

(\d{1}\b)       # followed by one digit, ending at a word boundary
                #   (ie whitespace or the end of the string)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for the normalizing. I do recommend using the `r` string prefix instead of `\\\t`, though.

Comment: @larsman: thank you, I have changed it to a raw string and reordered the character-list for easier comprehension.